# Hive ParseException missing EOF for Pivot

Tags: mysql, sql, hive, hiveql

I am trying to use pivot in Hive but it is raising parse exception. Can anyone suggest anything on this.

kbm_demo:

`kbm_individual_id`, `age_range`, `kbm_household_id`

```
(1, 'A', 'AGYDGYDGYEW'),
(2, 'B', 'AGYDGYDFDGD'),
(3, 'C', 'AGYDGYDGUGH')
```

kbm_demo_extrac:t

(`id`, `k_age_range`, `kbm_household_id`)

```
(1, Alpha, 'AGYEWUCUXUI'),
(2, Beta, 'AGERWREUUSS'),
(3, Gamma, 'AGYDWTSHAJG')
```

Expected Output:

```
      Alpha       Beta     Gamma
A       1           0        0
B       0           1        0
C       0           0        1
```

Query:

```
with cte as(
Select a.kbm_individual_id, a.age_range, b.k_age_range from kbm_demo a inner join kbm_demo_extract b on a.kbm_individual_id = b.kbm_individual_id)

Select age_range, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M from cte pivot
count(kbm_individual_id) for k_age_range in ([A], [B], [C], [D], [E], [F], [G], [H], [I], [J], [K], [L], [M]) as pivottable order by age_range asc
```

This raises parse exception at line 4 near pivot. Need suggestions on this

Comment: could you please provide some input data examples with desired output dataset?

Comment: @leftjoin Edited the question with input tables and expected output.